# How do I make the header on my website encapsulate the logo (put in with navbar-brand)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, header

When I added the logo using navbar-brand to my header page, it overlaps the divs on various pages rather than being encapsulated by the header, as seen in the picture attached:
[header overlapping divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ1P5.png)

Does anyone know how to make sure the logo is in the same div as the rest of the header?
Here is my code:

```
<header>
<nav class="navbar bg-transparent navbar-fixed-top py-5">
<div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <nav class= "py-5">
          <% if logged_in? %>
          <div class="col-sm-2">
            <%= link_to image_tag("logo1.png", size: "150x100", alt: "logo"), explore_path, class: 'nav navbar-brand navbar-left', id: 'logo-image' %>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <% @mentee = Mentee.find_by(user_id: current_user.id) %>
            <% @mentor = Mentor.find_by(user_id: current_user.id) %>
            <% if @mentee.nil? && @mentor.nil?%>
              <li><%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete %></li> 
            <% elsif current_user.mentee? %>
              <li><%= link_to "Profile", menteeprofile_path(@mentee), method: :get %></li> 
              <li><%= link_to "Matches", matches_path, method: :get %></li> 
              <li><%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete %></li> 
            <% elsif current_user.mentor? %>
              <li><%= link_to "Profile", mentorprofile_path(@mentor), method: :get %></li> 
              <li><%= link_to "Matches", matches_path, method: :get %></li> 
              <li><%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete %></li> 
            <% else %>
              <li><%= link_to "Profile", userprofile_path(current_user), method: :get %></li> 
              <li><%= link_to "Matches", matches_path, method: :get %></li> 
              <li><%= link_to "Profile", profile_path, method: :get %></li> 
              <li><%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete %></li> 
            </ul>
            <% end %>
          <% else %>
            <%= link_to image_tag("logo1.png", size: "150x100", alt: "logo"), "/", id: 'logo-image'%>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path  %></li> 
              <li><%= link_to "Sign up", "/users/new"  %></li>
            </ul>
          <% end %>
        </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </nav>
</header>
```

```
header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;//footer = 100, topmenu = 50
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff; 

  padding-bottom: 65px;
}
```